# Flutter background service not working using android_alarm_manager_plus or flutter_background_fetch

Tags: android, flutter, service, background-process, android-alarms

I'm working on a Flutter app only for Android, and I want to register a background service.

I've tried exactly how it's being mentioned on the plugin page, but unfortunately, I cannot make it run properly. [android_alarm_manager_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus)

The main purpose was to fetch an URL and display notifications (cannot use Google Play Services), but for the moment I would like to see it work, just by having a simple Toast message periodically when the app is closed.

I've also tried with their [example](https://github.dev/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/tree/main/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus/example) and cannot make it run. Tried with Flutter SDK  *2.8.0  and 2.10.0*, the latest version for *android_alarm_manager_plus* or older versions, and still cannot make it run.

Does someone else recently had similar issues?

**EDIT:** I've also tried an alternative using [flutter_background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) I've open an [issue](https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch/issues/278).

Environment:

```bash
Plugin version: latest
Platform: Android
OS version: API 30
Device manufacturer / model: emulator
Flutter info (flutter info, flutter doctor):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.0, on macOS 11.2.2 20D80 darwin-x64, locale en-GI)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc2)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
! Flutter recommends a minimum Xcode version of 13.
Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.65.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```